# HQL / Nested Eager Loading

Tags: java, hql, eager

I am wondering what the best way is to load nested values for lazy loaded objects.  I'm providing an example to help explain this better.

```
public class A{
    private B b; //Lazy loaded
    private C c; //Lazy loaded
    private D d; //Lazy loaded
}
public class B{
    private E e; //Lazy loaded
    private F f; //Lazy loaded
}
public class C{
}
public class D{
}
```

As an example I want to do:

```
System.out.println(a.getB().getE());
```

If I ran the above statement I'd get a lazy load exception.

I can always do the following:

```
for (A a : somePossiblyLargeList) {
    org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(a.getB().getE());
}
```

but obviously performance would suck.

Is there a way I can write a custom HQL query which returns A objects that are pre-populated with those specific nested fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course.

Use `join fetch` in your HQL query, as explained in the [Hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins) (that you should read):

```
select a from A a left join fetch a.b b left join fetch b.e e where ...
```

Comment: I think my actual situation is a bit trickier than my example...  This is a many-to-many mapping between A<->B with a link table called A_Lnk_B.  So, Class A contains a Set<A_Link_B>.  From that list, I'd have to iterate over the ids for every B.  Then I would take those ids in B to find E.  I have a hard time conceptualizing how this would be stored back into a java A object...

Comment: select a from A a left join fetch a.aLinkBs alb left join fetch alb.b b left join fetch b.e e where ...

Comment: I can't believe i used a `ResultTransformer` and wasted 3 hours when `select a ..` was the answer. Thanks!